# How to force a HTML dropdown menu to open on loading WordPress page

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I have an iFrame embedded in my WordPress page (using a custom HTML block) for massage bookings. https://aanmassage.nl/boek-jouw-massage/

The iFrame loads with a class [MenuGroup--header--443090](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JGFH.png), containing the various massages), but this MenuGroup is closed. When selecting the group title or the chevron, it opens and the massages show in a dropdown.

For users who want to book a massage, I find this very distracting. Is there a way to force the group to be opened by default? Using either html, js or css code.

[Screenshot with closed menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNAe6.png)

[Screenshot with opened menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4qft.png)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is an option that you can edit as an attribute for your iframe? The thing is, you need access to the Javascript file to edit that behaviour. But since you're using an iframe, I guess you don't have access right?

EDIT:

Well, you can paste this in a JS file, should work:

```
function eventFire(el, etype){
  if (el.fireEvent) {
    el.fireEvent('on' + etype);
  } else {
    var evObj = document.createEvent('Events');
    evObj.initEvent(etype, true, false);
    el.dispatchEvent(evObj);
  }
}

window.onload = function {
eventFire(document.querySelector('.MenuGroup--header--443090'), 'click');
}
```

What this does is replicate a click event on your website, so the menu opens on page load.

EDIT2:

Indeed, I forgot to take in account that iframe loading times are separate from window loading times, so using this instead might work better

```
function eventFire(el, etype){
  if (el.fireEvent) {
    el.fireEvent('on' + etype);
  } else {
    var evObj = document.createEvent('Events');
    evObj.initEvent(etype, true, false);
    el.dispatchEvent(evObj);
  }
}

document.querySelector("iframe").addEventListener( "load", function(e) {
    eventFire(document.querySelector('.MenuGroup--header--443090'), 'click');

} );
```

Comment: No, I don't have access to the sources. I can use additional javascript code with a plugin however.

Comment: This is not working. The event seems to be fired before the iframe is loaded. Probably I should load the iframe also from script?

Comment: You're right, the script should be ran on the Iframe instead. Check the edit

Comment: Thanks. Sadly it is still not working as expected.
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fireEvent' of null
    at eventFire ((index):50)
    at HTMLIFrameElement.<anonymous> ((index):60)